# iOS development certificate locally

Tags: xcode, app-store, keychain

I am receiving this error when trying to submit my app to the app store from xcode:

[image: error that is shown]

What am I doing that is wrong? I can't find a anwser that is relevant to Xcode 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to revoke certificates and recreate the profile using same Mac

Comment: Do I press the reset button then?

Comment: No , open your developer account and revoke the specific certificate and then create again. You can press reset but it will be confusing for you